# Python dictionary assignment missing

Tags: python

Python stores key/values in dictionaries.

In this example values (which are dictionaries themselves) are stored in "lut".

```
lut = {}
pair="  "
line = "halhak"
for letter in line.strip() + ' ':
                d = lut.setdefault(pair, {})
                d[letter] = d.get(letter, 0) + 1
                pair = pair[1] + letter
```

The key / values are:

```
for key in lut:
    print key, "/", lut[key]

   / {'h': 1}
ak / {' ': 1}
al / {'h': 1}
lh / {'a': 1}
ha / {'k': 1, 'l': 1}
 h / {'a': 1}
```

My question:
I don't see where the loop assigns any values to "lut" different from "{}".

Comment: `d` is a part of `lut`, and `d` is assigned a value, so `lut` changes. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Thanks, it would. But I don't see why d is part of lut?!

Comment: `setdefault` is responsible for that.

Answer (score 1):

`d` is always a reference to some element of `lut`. Here's a similar example that shows how it works.

```
>>> lut = {1 : {}}
>>> d = lut[1]
>>> d is lut[1]
True
```

`lut[1]` is a reference to some dictionary, and the value of `d` is a reference to that same dictionary, as verified by the `is` operator. Operations on `d` and operations on `lut[1]` operate on the same object.

In your actual code, a call to `setdefault` is involved:

```
d = lut.setdefault(pair, {})
```

The `setdefault` method does two things: if `pair` is not in `lut`, it first sets the value of `lut[pair]` to the given value. Then it returns the value of `lut[pair]`. It's identical to the following code

```
if pair not in lut:
    lut[pair] = {}
d = lut[pair]
```

Answer (score 0):

Only empty dicts  `{}` are directly added to `lut`, using `setdefault()`.

As described in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault), `setdefault` always returns a value for any given key:

> setdefault(key[, default])
>
> If key is in the dictionary, return its value. 
>    If not, insert key with a value of default and return default. default defaults to None.

So `d` is always a dict - one of the values in the outer `lut` dict.

However, the next line modifies one of these (initially empty) dicts out of `lut`,
which is why you see populated dicts in the results.

Comment: I was not aware that "=" is an assignement in this case. Is there a rule in Python when "=" assigns values or references?

Answer (score 0):

The expression `d = lut.setdefault(pair, {})` does one of two things, depending on wether or not the `pair` key is present:

1. `pair` is present; return a reference to the value
2. `pair` is not present; set `lut[pair]` to the second argument (`{}`), and return it.

Either way, you now have a reference to the object referenced by `lut[pair]`, which is always a dictionary.

Modifying that dictionary means that all references everywhere can see those changes. `d[letter] = d.get(letter, 0) + 1` will set a key-value pair in that dictionary. Since both `d` and `lut[pair]` reference that dictionary, you can later iterate over `lut` to see those changes.

A quick demo:

```
>>> lut = {}
>>> d = lut.setdefault('foo', {})
>>> lut
{'foo': {}}
>>> d
{}
>>> d is lut['foo']
True
>>> d['bar'] = 42
>>> d
{'bar': 42}
>>> lut
{'foo': {'bar': 42}}
>>> lut['foo']
{'bar': 42}
```

Comment: Thanks! For simple variables "=" assigns values. Is there a rule when "=" is a reference or value?

Comment: @Gantter: everything in Python is an object, and assignment always gives you a reference to that object.

Comment: @Gantter: some object types are immutable, so operations produce *new* objects; `foo = 10; foo = foo + 5` gives you a new object, `15`. But a dictionary is a mutable object, so you can manipulate it directly. `dict.setdefault()` is a method that manipulates the object, and `dictobject[key] = new_value` assigns directly to a key on the dictionary, not the `dictobject` name.

Comment: @Gantter: also see [Immutable vs mutable types - Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8056130)

Comment: a = 7; b = 8; a = b; print a; b = 9; print a; print b -> 8; 8; 9 (ie. a keeps the value 8)

Comment: @Gantter: yes, because `b` is rebound to a different object. `b = 9` changes what `b` references, not what `a` references. They may have started referencing the same thing, but don't continue to do so. See http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html and, for a visualisation: http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=a+%3D+7%0Ab+%3D+8%0Aa+%3D+b%0Aprint+a%0Ab+%3D+9%0Aprint+a%0Aprint+b&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=true&textReferences=false&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&curInstr=0

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments which introduce me to the beginning of deeper understandig of programming!